# Trying to parse byte slice as base 16 number in Golang

Tags: string, go

I'm trying to parse a slice of bytes with the below value `020000` to as a base 16 number but haven't gotten it working yet. What am I doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    input := []byte{0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    expectation := 131072

    actual := headerVersion(input)

    if actual != expectation {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Expected %v but got %v.", expectation, actual))
    }
}

func headerVersion(input []byte) int {
    output, _ := strconv.ParseUint(string(input), 16, 64)
    return int(output)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eM5RQAJdoL

Comment: `[]byte{0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}` is definitely not a hex representation of 131072. A hex string must be printable characters by definition. It's looks similar to a binary little endian representation, but it's neither 32 nor 64 bits.

Comment: 131072 as a big endian uint32 is `[]byte{0, 2, 0, 0}`, but you have a 6 bytes buffer. Are you certain that this is how the data is specified? Are you sure you're not supposed to be reading `020000` as the hex string itself? Parsing `[]byte{0, 2, 0, 1}` and `020100` are going to produce different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a raw byte slice that is the bytes making up the number you want, but you're instead parsing it as if it were the bytes making up the string representation of the bytes making up the number you want. Rather than attempting to parse as a string, parse as what it is - bytes. You can do this using the [`binary` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/), which, per its documentation:

> implements simple translation between numbers and byte sequences and encoding and decoding of varints.

Which is exactly what you want. How you use it will depend on the endianness and encoding of the data, but the documentation should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try to get your suggestion working.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! https://play.golang.org/p/0WaGkECOZS. As the play code shows it can be done like this: `binary.BigEndian.Uint32([]byte{0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0})`

Comment: @nbsp the `b[0:]` in your play code is verbose, `b` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Never omit errors, always check them!

```
func headerVersion(input []byte) int {
    output, err := strconv.ParseUint(string(input), 16, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return int(output)
}
```

Feeding `[]byte{0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}` to it, it will print:

```
strconv.ParseUint: parsing "\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00": invalid syntax
```

When you do `string(input)`, it converts the bytes of `input` interpreted as the UTF-8 encoded bytes of a text.

But `input` contains the *numerical* values of the digits, not the UTF-8 representation! The numerical value for a `0` digit is `'0'`, which equals to `48`.

So you have to shift the byte values by `'0'` (this demonstration only works if byte values are less than 10!):

```
func headerVersion(input []byte) int {
    for i := range input {
        input[i] += '0'
    }
    output, err := strconv.ParseUint(string(input), 16, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    return int(output)
}
```

Your original `headerVersion()` function would only give correct, valid result if you would feed it the following input:

```
input := []byte{'0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0'}
```

Comment: This still converts the bytes into a string and then parses the string back into bytes - I think the binary package is more efficient and more intuitive in this case.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, this isn't the fastest way, I was on to show why his solution doesn't work. To use the `encoding/binary` package, you would also have to merge 2 digits as that forms a `byte`.

Comment: 131072 as a 32 bit big endian int is `[]byte{0, 2, 0, 0}`, which seems to be the closest, but the fact that it's in a 6 byte buffer and asking about hex means that there is information missing from the question that we need to answer it either way.

Comment: @JimB The asker wants to convert the number `"20000"`, I don't know how (or rather _why_) he ended up with the byte values `0, 2, 0, 0, 0`, but using the byte values as  digits gives the expected result.

Comment: Exactly. Without knowing the specification, we can't be sure if 020100 is supposed to be 131328 or 131073.